# Select from two table with "and" condition and MIN() function

Tags: mysql, select, datatable, min

I have the table :

*ruletbl

```
| id_rule | code_rule |
-----------------------
|    1    |   R01     |
|    2    |   R01     |
|    3    |   R01     |
|    4    |   R02     |
|    5    |   R02     |
|    6    |   R02     |
-----------------------
```

and second table *detailRuletbl:

```
|  id_detailRule   | id_rule |  id_sym  |  codeDetailrule | orderNO |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1         |    1    |     1    |     R01#1       |    1   |
|        2         |    1    |     2    |     R01#1       |    1   |
|        3         |    1    |     3    |     R01#1       |    1   |
|        4         |    2    |     4    |     R01#2       |    2   |
|        5         |    2    |     1    |     R01#2       |    2   |
|        6         |    2    |     2    |     R01#2       |    2   |
|        7         |    3    |     4    |     R01#3       |    3   |
|        8         |    3    |     3    |     R01#3       |    3   |
|        9         |    3    |     1    |     R01#3       |    3   |
|        10        |    4    |     6    |     R02#1       |    1   |
|        11        |    4    |     7    |     R02#1       |    1   |
|        12        |    4    |     5    |     R02#1       |    1   |
|        13        |    5    |     4    |     R02#2       |    2   |
|        14        |    5    |     1    |     R02#2       |    2   |
|        15        |    5    |     2    |     R02#2       |    2   |
|        16        |    5    |     8    |     R02#2       |    2   |
|        17        |    6    |     6    |     R02#3       |    3   |
|        18        |    6    |     8    |     R02#3       |    3   |
|        19        |    6    |     2    |     R02#3       |    3   |
|        20        |    6    |     1    |     R02#3       |    3   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to select from those table with "and" condtiion in input one array (1,2) and MIN(orderNo) if "codeDetailrule is same like "R01#1 and R01#2" so first elimination with "and" condtion likes this code:

```
SELECT codeDetailrule, orderNo
FROM detailRuletbl
WHERE id_sym
IN ( 1,2 ) 
GROUP BY codeDetailrule
HAVING COUNT( * ) =2
```

the result :

```
| codeDetailRule  | orderNo |
----------------------------
|      R01#1     |    1    |
|      R01#2     |    2    |
|      R02#2     |    2    |
|      R02#3     |    3    |
----------------------------
```

and if we use MIN(orderNO) the result should be :

```
| codeDetailRule  | orderNo |
----------------------------
|      R01#1     |    1    |----------------------> this is my expect result
|      R02#2     |    2    |
----------------------------
```

Can anyone can help me?

Till now this is my trial :

```
SELECT codeDetailrule, orderNo
FROM detailRuletbl
WHERE id_sym
IN ( 1,2 ) 
GROUP BY codeDetailrule
HAVING COUNT( * ) =2
AND orderNo= ( SELECT MIN( X.orderNo) FROM detailRuletbl,
                (SELECT codeDetailrule, orderNoFROM detailRuletbl
                 WHERE id_sym IN ( 1, 2 ) GROUP BY codeDetailrule
                 HAVING COUNT( * ) =2
                 ) 
                 AS X
               )
```

and result :

```
|  codeDetailrule  | orderNo  |
-------------------------------
|    R01#1         |     1    |
-------------------------------
```

Anyone have any Idea? Please help.

Comment: @rlanvin...please check my update question that's my trial code...please help me. thanks

Comment: Why `R02#3     |    3 ` is eliminated in the result ? what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: R01#2 and R02#3 is eliminated....the logic is: MIN(orderNo) with the same     
codeDetailrule like "R01#1 and R01#2 they are the same code_rule in the 
first table *ruletable. and the R02#2 and R02#3 is the same also...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT codeDetailrule, orderNo
FROM detailRuletbl
WHERE id_sym
IN ( 1,2 ) AND orderNo IN (
SELECT MIN(orderNo) FROM detailRuletbl
                 GROUP BY orderNo
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood what you wanted

Comment: I will try it...mate.

Comment: When I try the result is empty result mate..... :(, and btw I think your code is too same with my code they never elimination for MIN(orderNo) when the codeDetailrules is the same like "R01#1 and R01#2"

Comment: Just try to use first subquery, maybe you can find problem. Additionaly, I can not undrestood what are u want to select. As I can understand, you want select some "id_sym", when orderNo is minimal. I'm right? But why do you need HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ?

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 for the condition "and"  if we are not using this condition they will be check with "or" condtion only one is true than execute, but I need 2, not only one. btw I have got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the rigth answer for MIN() function and check "and" condtion

```
SELECT a.codeRule, a.id_rule, MIN( a.orderNo) 
FROM (ruletbl AS b, detailRuletbl AS a)
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT h.codeDetailrule, h.id_rule AS irule, i.codeRule AS
             krule, MIN( h.oderNo) AS norderno
             FROM detailruletbl AS h, ruletbl AS i
             WHERE h.id_rule = i.id_rule
             AND h.id_sym
             IN ( 1,2 ) 
             GROUP BY h.codeDetailrule
             HAVING COUNT( * ) =2
           )sMin ON a.id_rule= sMin.irule
          GROUP BY sMin.krule
```